# Short numerical ID in URL - Generate and check against database

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier, friendly-url

I want to use a unique id in a friendly URL. I've read many answers that mostly based on UUID, GUID or hash of some sort.

I want a short numerical Id. I thought about generating a function that does the follows:

- Generate a four digit number
- Check if the number exists in the `UNIQUE bigint` column in MySQL
- If it exists, repeat the search (up to five times), if limit reach, go for five digits and so forth

The idea is to be able to get a unique short numerical Id. Is there any issue with this implementation.

Comment: Why not just create Auto Increment number and get the next value when you want to create something?

Comment: @ogres for several reasons: when running queries in a server farm which can lead to scalability issues, and second, the ID of the row reflect the number of items, and I don't want that information to be publicly visible.